# vscode uses different cocoapods version when running a task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

When I run `pod --version` from vscode terminal or macos integrated terminal I get version 1.13.0 which is a "correct" version for me, but when I run the same script as a vscode task I get 1.11.3.

Also `which pod` print `/Users/__/.rbenv/shims/pod` from terminal but `/usr/local/bin/pod` when running as a task.

Why is there a such kind of difference?